# I want this div to display and move up when menu is selected

Tags: javascript

I want this div to display and move up when menu is selected. Please can anyone help with the solution. Thanks so much

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
var divobject = null;
function init(id){
   divobject = document.getElementById('id');
   divobject.style.left = '25px'; 
   divobject.style.top = '580px';
   divobject.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function moveUp(id){
   divobject = document.getElementById(id);
   divobject.style.visibility = 'visible';
   divobject.style.left = '25px';
   divobject.style.top = parseInt(div.style.top) + 0 + 'px';
   divobject.style.position = 'absolute';
}
document.onclick =init; 
window.onload =init;
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(moveup('1'));">show div</a>
<div id="1">tytt</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Only javascript or can you use jquery ?

Comment: Dont use ids that start from numbers

Comment: what is `div.style.top`?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use ids that start from numbers

**change Your code to this**

```
function init(id){
   divobject = document.getElementById(id);
```

**Remove** these lines because you are not sending any arguments to functions, so it will generate error because `id` will be undefined

```
document.onclick =init; 
window.onload =init;
```

And if you want to add any value to existing style top, you cans use any value rather than 0, but enclose it in braces so that addition takes place, rather than string concatenation

```
divobject.style.top = (parseInt(divobject.style.top) + 0) + 'px';
```

Comment: Thanks, why I used id was because I have more than one div and I want to call them separate menu click

Answer (score 0):

Well, as mentioned you've got some issues in your code... 
I change it to somehow to work, although you need to change the approach if you want to create menu style control.

- Try to use style classes and switch it dynamically, see [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) toggle
- The element id should start with letters.
- The method are case sensitive
- id - is a variable, it should not be in commas.

Use the dev tools \ debugger.

```
    <html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
var divobject = null;
function init(id){
   divobject = document.getElementById(id);
   divobject.style.left = '25px'; 
   divobject.style.top = '580px';
   divobject.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function moveup(id){
   divobject = document.getElementById(id);
   divobject.style.visibility = 'visible';
   divobject.style.left = '25px';
   divobject.style.top = parseInt(div.style.top) + 0 + 'px';
   divobject.style.position = 'absolute';
}

window.onload = function(e) {                
    init("elt");
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="moveup('elt')">show div</a>
<div id="elt">tytt</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks pro, please I will like to apply this on multiple divs and to call them up with different menu clicks